# Sketchup Ruby Clipping mask API

Tags: ruby, sketchup

In Sketchup Ruby API, does it have any method for creating a clipping mask of imported image?.

If not, any suggestion for implementing it. ?

All suggesstion will be appreciated.
Thanks you

Comment: Can you elaborate what you mean by clipping mask? Do you mean trimming the face the image is applied to? Or do you mean modifying the texture data itself to make part of it transparent?

Comment: @thomthom: yes, i mean trimming the face of the image. It is like this example: http://help.sketchup.com/en/article/95936. But i need an API or function, not a existed GUI tool

Comment: In that case there is not API method in the SketchUp API. I take it this was what you where going for in the other thread?
TIG, over at SketchUcation made a tool like that, but he wrote it in Java and made console command to operate it. 
Since SU2014 we ship with the standard library so you can easily use gems that might fit your need. In earlier versions it'll be of a more challenge.

Comment: One alternative is to use a C/C++ library and write a Ruby C/C++ extension to interface with that. Would certainly ensure performance.

Comment: @thomthom: thanks you, i will try to write C/C++ library .
I asked you a lot of question about Ruby Sketchup API. But it is the first time , i ask about Ruby Clipping mask :)

Comment: We're about to release a Hello World example for a Visual Studio and Xcode project on making Ruby C++ Extension for SketchUp. Not quite ready right now, but soon. Keen an eye on our github account.

Comment: @thomthom: That's great. I will follow that post.
Ahh, i have got one Ruby C++ Extension Hello World example: https://bitbucket.org/thomthom/sketchup-ruby-c-extension/overview. Maybe it is yours. I tried , but i got one error, i will report my error later in your bitbucket account.